# how to append to an existing line using sed

Tags: unix, scripting, sed

I would like to output a file's contents appended with a string without creating a new line.

so far my command places the appended string on a new line:

```
sed -e 'a foo' file.txt
>> file contents...
>> foo
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
>> file contents...foo
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `sed` (tested successfully on `Archlinux` & `Minix`):

```
sed '$s/$/foo/' file.txt
```

`$` at the beginning, mean *end of **file***.

If you need to add *foo* on each lines :

```
sed 's/$/foo/' file.txt
```

In the latest context, `$` mean *end of **line***

Comment: I don't think the OP wants a newline character in there. Also, you don't need the braces. Also, there's no need for `awk` here.